# Borders on Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am making `div` based tables following this:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#table

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container px-4 mx-auto my-8">
  <div class="table w-full bg-white rounded shadow table-responsive text-center">
    <div class="table-header-group bg-gray-50">
      <div class="border-b border-gray-900 table-row">
        <div class="table-cell p-3 text-sm font-bold uppercase">Title</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3 text-sm font-bold uppercase">Artist</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3 text-sm font-bold uppercase">Year</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row-group divide-y divide-gray-700">
      <div class="table-row border-t border-gray-400 group hover:bg-gray-100">
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Chocolate Starfish And The Hot Dog Flavored Water</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Limp Bizkit</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">2000</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row border-t border-gray-400 group hover:bg-gray-100">
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Significant Other</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Limp Bizkit</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">1999</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row border-t border-gray-400 group hover:bg-gray-100">
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Three Dollar Bill, Y’all $</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">Limp Bizkit</div>
        <div class="table-cell p-3">1997</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you apply the `border-t border-gray-400 group hover:bg-gray-100` to a standard table `tr` this works fine.  Trying to dig through the Tailwind CSS but nothing obvious to me what is overriding this and hiding the top border from displaying. I even tried a `divide-y divide-gray-700` trick on the sudo-tbody div and that didn't work either.

Comment: Just add `.border-collapse` to your `.table`

Comment: Wow - simple as that.  Post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.border-collapse` to your `.table`.

Comment: what if you have grid not table